# Bind ajax request to link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to update the number of likes on my "ideas" page when someone hit the like button using ajax

The button is displayed as follows in the ideas#show view ( the path currently directs to likes#create without ajax)

```
  - unless signed_in? and current_user.likes? @idea
    = link_to "Like this idea!", idea_likes_path(@idea), :class => "btn btn-large btn-block btn-success", method: :post, id: 'like_button'
  - else
    = link_to "Unlike this idea", idea_like_path(@idea, current_user.idea_like(@idea)), :class => "btn btn-large btn-block btn-inverse", method: :delete
```

My application.js has the follow:

```
jQuery.fn.ajaxFormSubmit = function() {
  this.submit(function() {
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  })
  return this;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#like_button").ajaxFormSubmit();
})
```

the LikesController#create method:

```
  def create
    like = Like.new
    @idea.likes << like
    current_user.likes << like

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @idea }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

and finally the create.js.erb:

```
$("#like_count").html("<%= pluralize(@ideas.likes.count, 'Like') %>");
```

With the above code, the button still refreshes the whole page. How do I make AJAX work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit an AJAX request without writing any Javascript by using the `remote` option of the `link_to` helper.

```
= link_to "Like this idea!", idea_likes_path(@idea), :class => "btn btn-large btn-block btn-success", method: :post, remote: true
```

This will send an AJAX request to the `LikesController#create` action with the `JS` format.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: When I add remote: true I get a ActionView::MissingTemplate error

Comment: Never mind! My view folder was like instead of likes :(

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with UJS.

```
= link_to "Like this idea!", idea_likes_path(@idea), :class => "btn btn-large btn-block btn-success", method: :post, id: 'like_button', remote: true
```

Here `remote:true` does the trick.

And then in your controller.

```
def create
@idea = Idea.where(id: params[:idea_id]).first
current_user.likes.create({idea_id: @idea.id})

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @idea }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: When I add remote: true I get a ActionView::MissingTemplate error